# fprintf not writing "%" to file

Tags: c++, c

So I'm trying to write this line to a text file;

```
sprintf(line, "%d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %d, %s\n", 
          gen_no, total_time, 
          progp->total_fitness, 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[0], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[1], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[2], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[3], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[4], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[5], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[6], 
          0, 
          tree_as_char);

fprintf(fp, line);
fclose(fp);
```

Everything in the line is written correctly apart from when tree_as_char has "%" i.e. "%25" symbols in it (sometimes it writes one and then the proceeding char is escaped, sometimes it does't write any). All the other symbols in tree_as_char are written to the file correctly, and printing the line prints the % symbols correctly. Maybe I'm not escaping it properly somewhere?

Thanks!

Phil

Comment: Hint: what does the final `f` in `sprintf` and `fprintf` stand for?

Comment: @KVD: Yes, or something like that. OP is formatting the string twice.

Comment: @Rhymoid: You'll have to spell it out, even though I (belatedly) added it to my answer: `fputs` is the non-formatted alternative, the OP should go for, if he's using that `line` variable further down, if not changing `sprintf` to `fprintf`, and `line` to `fp` will do...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: apparently so. `fputs` (or even `fwrite`) is indeed a way to go. I'm not a fan of conflating formatting and output (even though `printf` is so tempting to use), as it (unavoidably) leads to the misunderstanding found in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fprintf` will treat any `%` symbol in second parameter as a formatter. Try `fprintf(fp, "%s", line);`.

Comment: ^ This. Or just kill the first `sprintf()` statement and put everything in one call to `fprintf()`

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear, just noticed you're writing `sprintf`, and *then* call `fprintf`. Now that's just not necessary. You can easily save on that `sprintf` call by writing:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %d, %s\n",
          gen_no, total_time, 
          progp->total_fitness, 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[0], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[1], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[2], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[3], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[4], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[5], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[6], 
          0, 
          tree_as_char);
```

That ought to work, and you won't have any more issues with the percent signs in the `tree_as_char` string. If you still need that `line` var for other things, you can choose: parse the line, adding secondary `%` chars before writing to the file pointer, use `fwrite`, *or*, better (perhaps): use `fputs`:

```
sprintf(line, "%d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %d, %s\n",
          gen_no, total_time, 
          progp->total_fitness, 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[0], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[1], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[2], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[3], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[4], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[5], 
          progp->entopy_breakdown[6], 
          0, 
          tree_as_char);
fputs(fp, line);
```

---

If you want to print a percent sign (`%`) using any of the `*printf` functions, you have to escape the percent sign itself. Just write `%%` to get one %:

```
printf("%d%%", 10);
```

will print 10%
If your `tree_as_char` contains percent signs, `fprintf` will just consider that as a placeholder, so you'll have to parse that string first, and add a second percent sign if needed.